# Existing Django project deployment using Apache and Mod_wsgi (windows)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-import

I have a django project which I took it from github. I would like to run the project on my local using apache server. I have installed apache and want to run the project. But I am always getting this error.

```
 raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s"
% (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'core.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No
module named cms.models
```

Please find the configuration I am using.

```
Python 2.7 
Django 1.4 
database in postgres
```

I have a project under mysite which is having the module name as core. There is also a setting files, but I dont know why it is not getting referred. I am also not able to sync with the database. I have been searching for a tutorial which gives me details of deploying a existing django project in localhost. I am able to create a new django project and able to run it in the default port.

Comment: does the project have a requirements file?  If so, did you run it?

Comment: the requirements file is a text file. how will it run?

Comment: requirements.txt list all of the dependencies that need to be imported.  Its often best to use virtualenv to separate project from other projects.  use pip to import requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the project code to PYTHONPATH.

The normal configuration steps:

1. add a django.wsgi

   import os, sys
   sys.path.append('your project module path')# set PYTHONPATH
   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'core.settings'
   import django.core.handlers.wsgi
   application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
2. add  django.wsgi to httpd-wsgi.conf

   WSGIScriptAlias / django.wsgi #your djang.wsgi path

Comment: I just have a mod_wsgi.so from where can i get the django wsgi. Also where can I find the httpd-wsgi.conf.

Comment: And  you must add your project module to sys.path.

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur if you have not appended cms.modules to the sys.path.

Use sys.path.append(/project folder path/cms.modules)