# Can a older version of django project work on higher version?

Tags: django, windows, django-models

I have a django project version 1.4 Is it possible to upgrade it to higher version so that it still works. Should I start the project again from scratch. Is so what are the steps? Is the a proper documentation of django for deployment of the project in windows.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, the django migration is something not very documented.
In my opinion, the best thing you can do to be quick and secure, is:

1. Check all the major changes between Django 1.4 and 1.7 (look for changelog and Djang website).
2. Take a look to your code to be aware of what part will be obsolete after the migration.
3. Do the migration, in a non-critic environment of course. For this purpose, don't touch to your code first, just upgrade the Django version
4. Fix your code until it works perfectly (run unit tests if you have some).
5. You're ready to do the migration in a production environment.

I did it between Django 1.6 and Django 1.7 (and migrating from Python 2.x to 3.x in the same time). It was easier than I had imagined. However, Django 1.4 to 1.7 could be a little bit longer, but nothing hard.

Comment: Can you please guide me through the steps. It would be great if you could share some docs to be followed. If possible you can write a blog it would help many.

Comment: I can't really be more specific because no one will process exactly the same way depending on its environment. If you're blocked in one of the steps, you can post another specific question on Stack Overflow to be helped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829698/existing-django-project-deployment-using-apache-and-mod-wsgi-windows issues in deployment even in 1.4 version